# filling a matrix with random integers from a range according to a rule

Tags: matlab, random, while-loop

I'm using the matrix as an initial population for multiobjective optimization using NSGA-II in matlab. The size of my chromosome vector,(C), is `1x192` and each gene must be within the range `0<=gene<=40` and the genes must be integers. The rule is that the sum of groupings of 6 genes must be less or equal to 40.that is:

```
sum(reshape(6,[]))<=40
```

I've use the following code but it outputs either an all-zero population matrix(population matrix=vertical concatenation of 500 chromosomes) or a matrix that does not satisfy the rule:

```
     X=zeros(500,192);
     while i<501
       r=randi(40,6,32);
        if nnz(((sum(r))./40)>1)==0
         X(i,:)=reshape(r,1,[]);
         i=i+1;
         clear r;
        else
         clear r;
        end
     end
```

It is also taking forever to exit the while loop.
What am I doing wrong here? Is there another way of doing the above?

I've also tried this:

```
i=1;
while i<17500
 r=randi([1,40],6,1);
 s=sum(r);
  if s<=40
   X(:,i)=r;
   i=i+1;
  else
   clear r;
  end
end
X=unique(X','rows')';
A=X(:,randperm(size(X,2)));
A=X(randperm(size(X,1)),:);
```

The above tries to create random columns that will be reshaped to the population matrix. But the numbers are repeating; i.e in the 17500(16448 after removing duplicate columns) columns there is no occurrence of the numbers 37 and 40. Is there any way I can optimize the spread of the generated random numbers?

@0x90
I have a vector,called 'chromosome', of size `1x192` and each successive group of 6 members(called phenotype) must sum to 40 or less. To make it clearer:
[image: problem details]
That is, each P must be an integer in the range 0 to 40 inclusive and the sum at each phenotype must be <=40. I need 500 chromosomes like this.

I hope it makes sense now. ><

Comment: I'm essentially trying to create a `6x32` matrix whose elements are integer members from the range [0,40] such that the sum of each column of the matrix is at most 40.

Comment: How do you want the elements in each row to be distributed? If the sum of each row is limited, the values in it would not be distributed uniformly...

Comment: Not rows, the sum  of each generated column must be 40. There must be at least comparable amounts of each integer from [0,40] but i mostly see integers below 30.

Comment: Are values allowed to be repeated in each column?

Comment: yes they are, provided they make the sum of the column equal or less than 40.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [randi([min,max],n,m)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html). `randint` is going to be deprecated.

```
>> r = randi([1,4],3,2)

r =

     3     3
     2     2
     4     4
```

Comment: I tried the `randi([1,4],3,2)` thing but it still does not exit the while loop. On top of that my Matlab crashed T_T.

Comment: Why do you do it in a loop ?

Comment: I have to fill up a population matrix of size 500 by 192 using vectors that satisfy the rule. How can i do this without loops?

Comment: If you could rewrite your question we might could help you.

Comment: I added explanation (picture). Hope its better now.